# Python read YAML: where does it go wrong: with open() or yaml.load()?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have a script which loads a YAML file as an object. The related part is very simple:

```
def run_test_spec(self, file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            test_spec = yaml.load(f)
        if test_spec:
            do_test(test_spec)
        else:
            print("empty test_spec")
    except BaseException as err:
        print("error in loading yaml file:", file_path)
```

The *file_path* was passed in after finishing some comparisons on file entries with `for entries in os.scandir(some_directory)` (there is no `break` statement within the `for` loop).

It has been running fine until recently. The `test_spec` gets the value `None` after the first run. I debugged it with Pycharm. It the breakpoint is set at the line `if test_spec:`, `test_spec` is None but if the breakpoint is set either at the line `with open(...)` or `yaml.load()`, `test_spec` gets loaded properly. In the end, I added a `time.sleep(0.2)` statement before `with open(...)`, then it works all the time.

What was the likely cause of it? Is it the problem of `with open(...)` or `yaml.load()`? How do get it right without the sleep?

*Edited on June 27, 2018,*

I did further debugging, and found the line in the code which makes the difference. In file `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py` on my machine:

```
def update_raw(self, size=4096):
    data = self.stream.read(size)
    if self.raw_buffer is None:
        self.raw_buffer = data
    else:
        self.raw_buffer += data
    self.stream_pointer += len(data)
    if not data:
        self.eof = True
```

If the breakpoint is set to the first line (`data = ...`), `data` is read fine with the content of the file, however, it the breakpoint is set to the second line (`if self.raw_buffer is None:`), `data` is read in as an empty string, which caused a `StreamEndEvent` and thus the empty return from `yaml.load()`.

I could not step in `self.stream.read(size)`, which only got me to some code in `/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py`.

I don't think it is the Python library caused this problem. Probably it has something to do with my code. I noticed this happens after I run a test, which involves spawning two child processes running as pipe and kills the second process with `terminate()`. I checked the program with `psutil`, there is only one thread, no child processes, no open files after the run. Looks like it is clean. But then the new request files could not be read, unless I added a sleep or did a break before the stream read. If the second process, also in a pipe, terminates by itself, the issue does not occur.

If no breakpoint is set but just print the `f.tell()` before calling `yaml.load(f)`, it is always 0, whether the `yaml.load(f)` returns None or not.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate question. I tried `yaml.safe_load()` before and version 4.1  today. Still has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

PyYAML got a [new release](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/74) yesterday (2018-06-26). There were no announcements that this indicated an API break, but as can be expected from the major version number change there was.

The (unsafe) `load()` that you use has been renamed 
`danger_load()` by the merge of [this PR](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/74)

You can pin your PyYAML install on 3.x ( `pip install "pyyaml<4"` ) or change your code to use  `danger_load()`. The best solution would probably be to write explicit representers for the objects that now are dumped using `!!python/path_to_your_type`, so you can use the `safe_load()`.

I could not find any announcement of possible breakage in the documentation.